# Unity on Windows: Can the hash suffix ("_hXXXXXXX") created by PlayerPrefs be disabled?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to save some data to registry with PlayerPrefs, that is supposed to be read by another program. But when writing a value with the name "TestString", it ends up as "TestString_h3703777734" in the registry. This seems to be expected behaviour according to the docs (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). But since this behaviour is only described in the "In-Editor Play mode storage location", I'm thinking this could be a bug in the Standalone mode. It's important to note, that Unity itself has no trouble reading the value back when given just "TestString", but other programs don't know about Unity's hashing and thus don't know what keys to look for.

So basically the question is: Is it possible to disable this hashing behaviour?

Tested versions: 2020.3.15f2, 2020.3.4f1

Comment: Why do you go through the `PlayerPrefs`? You should use normal FileIO to communicate with another program ... or if it does need to be the registry then edit the registry directly e.g. using [`Registry.SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue)

Comment: @derHugo That is actually a good point. And something we have considered already, but PlayerPrefs is inherently cross-platform. So using Registry directly is of course an option to get it working now. We were just thinking it might be nice to know if there is a way with PlayerPrefs as well.

Comment: if you can find and define character value at hashed value starts, 
you can take a valuable data for string manipulation.

Comment: @Chris_benntec `but PlayerPrefs is inherently cross-platform` .. yes ... but the Registry not at all anyway .. on other target platforms it isn't in the registry so your other program can not get it from the registry either ...